# Examples of groups in the real world

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, education

I'm looking for some examples of groups in the real world to show students in a liberal arts math course. For example the Rubik's cube. Keep in mind these students have only a college algebra background.

Comment: Very similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65300/real-world-uses-of-algebraic-structures?rq=1

Comment: @Listing The question you refer to is to technical for the population of students I'm considering. I looking for examples provided by familiar things you could present to the average person on the street.

Comment: The group of plane isometries, and the subgroup of rotations/translations. Maybe that's too obvious.

Comment: Permutation groups (e.g., shuffling cards).

Comment: The seven Frieze groups are a standard photo project for our liberal arts math class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In music, the cyclic group of order $12$, $\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z=\{0,1,\ldots,11\}$, occurs as the group of intervals in the chromatic scale ($\mathbb Z$) modulo octave equivalence ($12\mathbb Z$). It has exactly four generators: $\pm 1$ (semitones up and down) and $\pm 7$ (perfect fifths up and down). The group acts freely and transitively on the set of $12$ pitch classes $\{C, C\sharp, \ldots, B\}$. The orbit of the generator $1$ is called the chromatic circle. The orbit of the generator $7$ is called the circle of fifths. (Both orbits are the same set, the set of all $12$ pitch classes, with a different graph structure.)

Answer (score 2):

The [group of permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group) of $52$ objects can be identified with
   shuffling a deck of cards. Every time someone shuffles a pack they are performing a group operation.

There are some nice card tricks that involve group theory. I don't remember the details exactly, but one involves addition [modulo four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) in relation to the suits.